# Look up python dict value by expression

Tags: python, optimization

I have a dict that has unix epoch timestamps for keys, like so:

```
lookup_dict = {
    1357899: {} #some dict of data
    1357910: {} #some other dict of data
}
```

Except, you know, millions and millions and millions of entries. I'd like to subset this dict, over and over again. Ideally, I'd love to be able to write something like I can in R, like:

```
lookup_value = 1357900
dict_subset = lookup_dict[key >= lookup_value]
# dict_subset now contains {1357910: {}}
```

But I confess, I can't find any actual proof that this is something Python can do without having, one way or the other, to iterate over every row. If I understand Python correctly (and I might not), key lookup of the form `key in dict` uses binary search, and is thus very fast; any way to do a binary search, on dict keys?

Comment: Keys are unique and have a single corresponding value. They are either in the dictionary or not. I don't understand this question.

Comment: Keys are hashed - not in btrees. So, perhaps you want to look at the `bisect` module maintaining a list as the keys, and a list of dictionaries as corresponding values - and use slicing after you've found the appropriate indices....

Comment: @JonClements: That works, but I'd suggest using one of the two `sortedlist` recipes that wraps `bisect` (or maybe one that doesn't, like the one in `blist`), because `bisect`-based code is pretty hard to read and easy to get off-by-one errors in.

Comment: How do you create the lookup_dict?  Perhaps if you are able to create it or sort/convert it as an OrderedDict instead then you will be able to some neat tricks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this without iterating, you're going to need the keys in sorted order. Then you just need to do a binary search for the first one `>= lookup_value`, instead of checking each one for `>= lookup_value`.

If you're willing to use a third-party library, there are plenty out there. The first two that spring to mind are [`bintrees`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/bintrees/1.0.0) (which uses a red-black tree, like C++, Java, etc.) and [`blist`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/blist/) (which uses a B+Tree). For example, with `bintrees`, it's as simple as this:

```
dict_subset = lookup_dict[lookup_value:]
```

And this will be as efficient as you'd hope—basically, it adds a single `O(log N)` search on top of whatever the cost of using that subset. (Of course usually what you want to do with that subset is iterate the whole thing, which ends up being O(N) anyway… but maybe you're doing something different, or maybe the subset is only 10 keys out of 1000000.)

Of course there is a tradeoff. Random access to a tree-based mapping is O(log N) instead of "usually O(1)". Also, your keys obviously need to be fully ordered, instead of hashable (and that's a lot harder to detect automatically and raise nice error messages on).

If you want to build this yourself, you can. You don't even necessarily need a tree; just a sorted `list` of keys alongside a `dict`. You can maintain the `list` with the `bisect` module in the stdlib, as JonClements suggested. You may want to wrap up `bisect` to make a sorted list object—or, better, get one of the recipes on ActiveState or PyPI to do it for you. You can then wrap the sorted list and the `dict` together into a single object, so you don't accidentally update one without updating the other. And then you can extend the interface to be as nice as `bintrees`, if you want.

Comment: Holy crap. Thanks! This... is pretty much excellent, and exactly what I wanted to know. As you correctly discerned (though I, uh, may not have made it sufficiently clear in my question), the goal is to take a set of ~200M rows and wind up with a subset in the single digits, and the lookup is... complicated. But it makes me *very* willing to use 3rd party libraries; I'll have a look at `bintrees`. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

Using the following code will work out

```
some_time_to_filter_for = # blah unix time
# Create a new sub-dictionary
sub_dict = {key: val for key, val in lookup_dict.items() 
            if key >= some_time_to_filter_for}
```

Basically we just iterate through all the keys in your dictionary and given a time to filter out for we take all the keys that are greater than or equal to that value and place them into our new dictionary

Comment: The question was "how to do it without iterating". Also, do not use `items()`.

Comment: `items()` is ok on python 3

Comment: @wim I know, but I still think that all uses of Python 2 should be explicitly marked as such.

Comment: @wRAR .items() is fine for 2,7

Comment: @wRAR I run python on 2.7 at my workplace and home and .items() is supported by 2.7

Comment: @Greg but I didn't say it is not supported, I've said you should not use it as it creates a copy. Read its docs.

Comment: @wRAR I'm straining to find a place where you mentioned that in this post.